# User prompt won't go away

Tags: java, jar, exe, code-signing, prompt

I recently created a Java program, and in an effort to give the desktop application its own icon, create a .bat file that ran the .jar and then converted the .bat to an .exe using a free converter.

The problem I am having is that whenever I run the exe, windows prompts the user asking if you want to run a program from an unknown publisher.

How can I make that go away?  How do I sign my program?

Comment: a simple way is to turn off UAC on your system (if possible).

Comment: I am using windows 7. Intend to have other users, eventually, download the program, so I dont think I can tell them to turn off their UAC.  That might seem sketchy.

Answer (score 1):

> ..give the desktop application its own icon..

Deploy it using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info). JWS works on any platform for which the J2SE is available (as opposed to just Windows), and offers desktop shortcuts and menu items with icons (amongst many other neat features).

If you need to digitally sign your app. for webstart, see the [File Service demo.](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs), which comes complete with source & build file.

---

While this might not be an answer to the stated question, it achieves the combined goal of creating a desktop icon for an app., while not showing a CLI.